# Azure AD B2C add claim to sign in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have added

```xml
<ClaimType Id="IdType">
  <DisplayName>Identification type</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
  <Restriction>
    <Enumeration Text="CC" Value="CC" SelectByDefault="false" />
    <Enumeration Text="CE" Value="CE" SelectByDefault="false" />
    <Enumeration Text="TI" Value="TI" SelectByDefault="false" />
  </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

The explanation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-configure-signup-self-asserted-custom. I did that example.

I need to use a username with two fields, so the authentication would like the image bellow:
[image]

In the user profile, I combined both fields, Type (ddl field) and username:[image]

So, basically, what I need to achieve is to authenticate with a two fields username, merge both values in the username field (so it's unique). Did anyone go through this?

Comment: Can you explain whether you are authenticating the user against Azure AD or an external IDP? What protocol does that IDP use? And will you be sending this claim to that IDP for authentication (along with other claims such as username, password, etc.)?

Comment: Hello, i used https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/LocalAccounts for my example, thanks

Comment: That is just the starter pack for the custom policies. It is still not clear whether YOU want to use your own IDP or are you authenticating against the AD. The image you show above is of the user record in the directory, but did you create the account using B2C sign up, or did you go to the Azure portal directly and created the account?

Comment: i created the account directly in azure portal